# Is it wrong to leave out the "v=DKIM1;" on a DKIM record?

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim

Looking at my mail hosting provider's already-populated DNS records, I see that their auto-generated DKIM record doesn't have `v=DKIM;` in it - it is simply

```
k=rsa; p=hGF6ksa9fjf8SD6bcKk...
```

in the record value.

Is this still considered a "valid" DKIM record? Do I need to contact them to have them add the `v=DKIM1;` in? (The associated Name is correct.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[RFC 6376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376), which defines DKIM, states the following about the `v` tag in the key record:

> v= Version of the DKIM key record (plain-text; RECOMMENDED, default
> is "DKIM1").  If specified, this tag MUST be set to "DKIM1"
> (without the quotes).  This tag MUST be the first tag in the
> record.  Records beginning with a "v=" tag with any other value
> MUST be discarded.  Note that Verifiers must do a string
> comparison on this value; for example, "DKIM1" is not the same as
> "DKIM1.0".

Since it is RECOMMENDED and defaults to DKIM1, this record is compliant with the RFC and should work with all compliant implementations.  (In other words, you should be fine.)